Question from Silverman Example X.4.10
I have a question about an argument in Example X.4.10 of Silverman's Arithmetic of Elliptic Curves. In the $d=17$ case he is considering the homogenous space:
$$C_{17} \colon 17 w^2 = 17^2 + 12 \cdot 17z^2 - 32 z^4$$
and he wishes to show that $C_{17}(\mathbb{Q}_{17})=\emptyset$. Suppose to the contrary that we have a solution with $w,z \in \mathbb{Q}_{17}$
The argument I would give is that the $17$-adic valuation of the left-hand side is odd. On the other hand, writing $k=\mathrm{ord}_{17}(z)$, we have:
$$ \mathrm{ord}_{17}(\mathrm{RHS})\geq \min \{ 2,1+2k,4k \}$$
with equality unless all of those terms are equal. Thus the only way this valuation can be odd is if $1+2k$ is the least term; however, one easily checks that this is never the case for any $k$, finishing the proof.
Silverman gives an argument which is similar in spirit but different in detail. The first thing he says is:

Since $\mathrm{ord}_{17}(17w^2)$ is odd and $\mathrm{ord}_{17}(32z^4)$ is even, we see that necessarily $z, w \in \mathbb{Z}_{17}$.

He then uses this observation to start reducing the equation modulo higher powers of $17$ until a contradiction is reached.
My question: How is Silverman deducing the integrality of $w$ and $z$ without simply resorting to the argument I gave above?

LHS has odd $,\nu_{17},$ but RHS has $\rm\color{#c00}{even}$, by $\ \begin{align}&k\le 0,\Rightarrow, \color{#c00}{4k}<1!+!2k<2\ &k\ge1 ,\Rightarrow,\ \  \color{#c00}2<1!+!2k<4k\end{align}\ \ $

If $z$ has negative valuation, then by the ultrametric inequality the RHS has valuation $\text{ord}_{17}(32z^4)$, which is impossible since this cannot equal $\text{ord}_{17}(17w^2)$ by parity. Showing that $w$ is integral is similar, noting that $\text{ord}_{17}(w)< 0$ implies $\text{ord}_{17}(z) < 0$ and again applying the ultrametric inequality to show that the RHS has valuation $\text{ord}_{17}(32z^4)$.
